# How to print svg in java?

Tags: java, svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="12cm" height="12cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="500" y2="200" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" />
     <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" /> 
</svg>
```

I want to print these svg codes in java. I know I should use print method to do this, but every time I tried to compile the java program I would get a bunch of errors. Please help me. Here are my codes:

```
class svg{
    puclic static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("
            <?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>
            <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" 
            \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">
            <svg width=\"12cm\" height=\"12cm\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\"
            xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">
            <line x1=\"100\" y1=\"100\" x2=\"500\" y2=\"200\" stroke=\"red\" stroke-width=\"5\" />
            <circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"100\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" /> 
            </svg>
            ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code, show the "bunch of errors" you're getting. Until then, no one can help you.

Comment: can you upload the *a bunch of errors* you have stated in your question so that we know that the errors are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use linebreaks within a `String` like that. If you want to keep them, they must be escaped with `\n`

Also, you misspelled `public`.

On top of that, you forgot a `;` at the end.

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print(
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
        "<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\"\n" + 
        "\"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n" +
        "<svg width=\"12cm\" height=\"12cm\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\"\n" +
        "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">\n" +
        "<line x1=\"100\" y1=\"100\" x2=\"500\" y2=\"200\" stroke=\"red\" stroke-width=\"5\" />\n" +
        "<circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"100\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" />\n" + 
        "</svg>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But actually these codes should print an image that is a black circle with a red line. How to modify the print method in order to print that in the console?

Comment: The Console cannot display images, especially not if all you have is some XML describing it. You will need a GUI of some sort for that. I would suggest you look up a Swing tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on how to add line breaks to a string. This is done by `+`. Also don't forget to surround strings with `"`.

If you want to format arbitrary test to Java-escaped strings then I suggest you have a look at some online tools like [Free Online Java or .Net Escape Tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html) (you can find them via Google).

This one will escape your XML so that it looks as follows. The program will then compile and print the XML onto the console.

```
package so;

public class StringFormatter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(

                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \r\n  \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\r\n<svg width=\"12cm\" height=\"12cm\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\"\r\n     xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">\r\n     <line x1=\"100\" y1=\"100\" x2=\"500\" y2=\"200\" stroke=\"red\" stroke-width=\"5\" />\r\n     <circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"100\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" /> \r\n</svg>"

                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But this time I got "Could not find or load main class". Why this happens? I've changed my file name to StringFormatter.

Comment: Probably because of the name of my class StringFormatter. Maybe you used a different class name? How do you call the Java program?

Answer (score 0):

1 Change `puclic` to `public`

2 Add a semi-colon to the end of your System.out.println statement

3 Use line terminators if you want line breaks

```
class svg {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" + 
            "<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\"             \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n" + 
            "<svg width=\"12cm\" height=\"12cm\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\"            xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">\n" + 
            "<line x1=\"100\" y1=\"100\" x2=\"500\" y2=\"200\" stroke=\"red\" stroke-width=\"5\" />\n" + 
            "<circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"100\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" /></svg>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the string code in multiple lines , then you need to use "+" concatenation sign. Or else you can write whole code in one line.

```
  class svg{
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.print("" +
            "            <?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>" +
            "<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" " +
                "\"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">" +
                "<svg width=\"12cm\" height=\"12cm\" viewBox=\"0 0 1000 1000\"" +
                "xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\">" +
                "<line x1=\"100\" y1=\"100\" x2=\"500\" y2=\"200\" stroke=\"red\" stroke-width=\"5\" />" +
                "<circle cx=\"200\" cy=\"100\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" /> " +
                "</svg>");
}
}
```

Above code will print whole string in one line. In case you want to add to in different line than you can use different print statement for each line or add \n in string.